# Multiply Dimension item with the numeric values

Tags: mdx

I have Dimension column as Price and the Measure column as Quantity, I want to multiply price with the quantity,Please help me write MDX.

I tried with the below query.

With Member [Measures].[A] As ([Part ID].[Price]), Format_String ='Number'

Member [Measures].[B] As [Measures].[Quantity] * [Measures].[A]

Select {[Measures].[A],[Measures].[B]} On Columns, NON EMPTY( [Part ID].[Part Id].Children ) On Rows from [studio_bomdata]

Answer (score 0):

You just need the following change

With Member [Measures].[A] As ([Part ID].[Price].CurrentMember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)
)